# Javascript regex to remove anything but numbers from the start of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some strings like this:

`var st1 = 'AU$99.95';` // Should return `99.95`

`var st2 = 'AU.99.95';` // Should return `99.95`

`var st1 = 'Blahblah $99,000';` // Should return `99,000`

My current regex gets me most of the way there, I'm just using `string.replace(/[^0-9.,]/g, "");`.

This works for all scenarios except for #2, when there is an allowed character that is before a number. I want to ONLY allow `.` and `,` when there is a number preceding it. How can I achieve this?

(I know I can write a javascript function to do this, but I'd rather take care of it all in the one regex replace)

EDIT:

Apologies, small oversight. I also need to remove any text after the number (I assumed before/after numbers wouldn't make a difference, but apparently they do!). So:

`var st4 = 'blahblah $.99,000AUD` // should return `99,000`

Comment: what about `$99.99 only`

Comment: @Anirudh Great point. If you make an answer with this updated query I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
str.replace(/^[^\d]*/,"").replace(/[^\d]*$/,"");
```

Answer (score 4):

maybe

```
string.replace(/^[^0-9]*/, "");
```

Comment: This matches the empty prefix and forces a replacement even when the first character is a digit. Use `/^[^0-9]+/` to prevent this.